# Would it be possible to add a title field to the link modal

Tags: feature-request

Currently in the WYSIWYG question/answer editor the add link tool opens a modal/pop-up form enabling you to paste the link URL.

I normally expect that a pop-up link form without a link title field does the job on it's own like an embed.ly service integration or something like that.

Would it be possible to add an additional text field to the modal so that you can enter the link title already there?

Comment: Currently, it either uses the selected text or, if no text is selected, automatically selects the link text so that you can type over it once the pop-up is dismissed. Why would it be better to have the textbox in the pop-up?

Comment: Avoids confusion IMO, you can still keep the current behavior, just add the field, so that the user doesn't forget to type the title. If text is selected, it gets inserted into the text field. If the text field is empty at the time when the user commits the content, the default title gets selected. I think it would help me at least, lately I'm like a goldfish...